# Magento 2.2.3 Order variables in success page

Tags: magento2

This question has been asked a few times and I still don't get it. Relatively new to Magento and not very good with PHP.

I would like to customize the checkout success page. So I overrode it by placing it in my theme (worked). But I would like to display the ordered items / the full address and the name of the customer.

Tried to write a module, but failed on that. Now I'm using the object manager (not recommended, I know):

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
              $orderData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
```

This works fine, I can get my order amount or status. But I can not get the name or address. I can get things like

```
[entity_id] => 78
[state] => new
[status] => pending
```

But I can't use this, because it is empty:

```
<p><?php echo($orderData->getCustomerFirstname()) ?></p>

[customer_firstname] => 
[customer_lastname] => 
[customer_middlename] =>
```

Also, I wold like to display the items grid like on the card.

Can anyone help? Would really appreciate it.

Cheers
Valentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guest customer **$order->getCustomerFirstname()** is null, in that case you can get from customer billing address. Try following way:

```
<?php if($order->getCustomerId()) :?>
    <?= $order->getCustomerEmail() ?>

    <?= $order->getCustomerFirstname() ?>

    <?= $order->getCustomerLastname() ?>

<?php else :?>
    <?php $billing = $order->getBillingAddress()?>
    <?= $billing->getEmail() ?>

    <?= $billing->getFirstname() ?>

    <?= $billing->getLastname() ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Don't use **$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();**

Create new module and try following way:

**Replace SR and Stackexchange to YourVendorName and YourModuleName.**

You can overwrite success block following way:

**app/code/SR/Stackexchange/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="SR\Stackexchange\Block\Checkout\Success"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/SR/Stackexchange/Block/Checkout/Success.php**

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Block\Checkout;


class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    protected $order;

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        if(!$this->order) {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
            $this->order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        }

        return $this->order;
    }
}
```

Now add following code for getting order object inside success.phtml:

```
<?php $order = $block->getOrder()?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried with object manager and it worked, just had to change $order to$orderData. Trying with the module now, but "$order" == NULL. Do you have an idea why that could be?

Comment: @ValentinPKStore when ever you change the di.xml you need to compile: php bin/magento setup:di:compile